# Can "yum history undo" be done from a local repository?

Tags: repository, local, yum

I have a local repository with some packages. When I update I use -c flag to pass a configuration file with my local repository. Is it possible to do the same with yum history undo? I have try to pass the flag in the same way with no success.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `-c` flag is a general yum option. It should be accepted by `yum history undo` just fine. Whether the history mechanism uses repositories in a way to make that make sense I don't know though. Is there a reason you don't just add your repository to the normal configuration (and then use `--disablerepo=` or `--enablerepo=` as necessary)?

Comment: I was considering that option also. I just wanted to know if the yum history undo can accept the flag and conf file, since I'm currently using that conf file to do the updates. But when I pass down the flag, the history undo command always fails.

Comment: Fails how? What happens?

Comment: Its fails when I'm trying to undo a downgrade from a package.
Error message:
Failed to downgrade: packagexxx...

Comment: Your custom config enables the repositories you are using by default, right? You don't also need to `--enablerepo=...` them? Are you trying to undo an upgrade? Does your repository have the older package in it? Do you have the older rpm cached on your local system?